# Timeout Question about Invoking a Remote WCF Service

Tags: wcf

When I invoke a remote WCF service I get the following timeout:

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.2810338. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Please note that I am sending a single object which is LOADED with a LOT of data.

Any ideas how to fix this issue and is this a problem on the client (ME) or the Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the size, have you tried increasing your maxBufferSize/maxReceivedMessageSize in your binding?

Comment: You mean Client binding right? If so I have not done so! I will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chunk your data into smaller pieces if possible and try again. This is a server setting that you will need to work around or request that the service provider increase it.

Comment: That would be ideal to chunk it into smaller pieces but the problem is that the remote service excepts a single object parameter and that object is populated like crazy!

Comment: I hope you're a paying customer and can either get them to up their timeout setting then.

Comment: I am thinking that it should be related to the receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00". Looks like SendTimeout is set to 1 minute.

Comment: Even if you can set a timeout value in your request, it might not be able to exceed the value on the server.

Comment: If the server or the owner of the WCF service increase the timeout values and then I do update service ref should I get the latest timeout values or do I have to update them manually.

Comment: As long as (server-timeout-setting) > (time-needed-to-process-your-request < request-timeout-parameter) you won't need to update your request values.

Answer (score 1):

Without a stack trace I'm can't be 100% sure, but I'm relatively certain this is a client side exception. If you know it's going to take more than a minute to send the data all you need to do is change the sendTimeout on your binding to be whatever amount of time you need it to be.

Comment: I set it up to 1 hour on the client side App.config file but I still got the same error back.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please??